# yAxes not re-render new data in Chart.js with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

Hi I try using the `Line` chart in my project but get an error you can see it in the image below

`package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-chartjs-2": "^4.1.0",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",    
},
```

`Chart code`

```
 const data = {
        labels: coinTimeStamp,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Price in USD.',
                data: coinPrice,
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: '#0071bd',
                borderColor: '#0071bd'
            }
        ]
    }

    const options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [
                {
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

```
<Line data={data} options={options}  />
```

and I get these two errors in the browser console

[image]

and `thanks`

Answer (score 0):

add the following to the import section

```
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
);
```

this will fix the issue

and this---

for Invalid scale config. for scale: yAxes, I removed the first array, I think it was and left it like this:

```
const options = { scales: { y: { ticks: { beginAtZero: true, }, }, }, };
```

https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_cryptoverse/issues/26